# Adding Score Label Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, label

I have an int for my score:

```
int score=0;
```

I understand how to add to the score, I just don't know how to display it

this is what I have but I'm pretty sure its wrong:

```
CCLabelTTF *scorelabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"score" fontName:@"Verdana-Bold" fontSize:18.0f];
```

---

```
int score=0;
CCLabelTTF *scorelabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"score" fontName:@"Verdana-Bold" fontSize:18.0f];
[self addChild:scorelabel];
```

---

Any advice on how to display the score on the scene?

Thank you

Code now

```
int score=0;
CCLabelTTF *scorelabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d",score] fontName:@"Verdana-Bold" fontSize:18.0f];  **The warning**
scorelabel.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
scorelabel.position = ccp(0.0f, 0.0f);
[self addChild:scorelabel];
```

backButton

```
CCButton *backButton = [CCButton buttonWithTitle:@"[ Menu ]" fontName:@"Verdana-Bold" fontSize:18.0f];
backButton.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
backButton.position = ccp(0.85f, 0.95f); // Top Right of screen
[backButton setTarget:self selector:@selector(onBackClicked:)];
[self addChild:backButton];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the label to your scene. If you are in the init method of a scene, you can use this line:

```
[self addChild:scorelabel];
```

Also, your score label includes the text "score" but not the actual score. If you want to include the score, change the creation of the label to this:

```
CCLabelTTF *scorelabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d",score] fontName:@"Verdana-Bold" fontSize:18.0f];
```

Comment: `int score=0;
    CCLabelTTF *scorelabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"score" fontName:@"Verdana-Bold" fontSize:18.0f];
    [self addChild:scorelabel];`

Its bringing up a warning sign that said the variable Score is being unused 

Thank you :)

Comment: Are you using it anywhere? Check the second line in my answer

Comment: Also run your project and check if the label is displaying at all

Comment: No the label is not showing up
I also added to the code (see my edit above) because I believe that is the way to position the label
Also its putting up a warning saying "Local declaration of 'score' hide instance variable"

Comment: to fix that warning, change the name "score" to something else.

Comment: Its in the `- (id)init` class because I noticed that there where other labels and buttons there

Comment: That's the method. What is the filename that xcode shows? Also, are the other labels showing up?

Comment: Its in the GameScene.m

Comment: Alright. Are you sure you're displaying the gamescene? Are the other gamescene labels showing up?

Comment: try and give the label a non zero position like ccp(0.5f, 0.8f)

Comment: The app crashes and says the problem is here `CCLabelTTF *scorelabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d",score] fontName:@"Verdana-Bold" fontSize:18.0f];` Thank you very :)

Comment: No it just takes me to that line of code and says "Thread 1: Breakpoint 1.1"

Comment: Look to the left of that line for a blue arrow. If there is one there drag it away and let go to delete it. You may have accidentally set a breakpoint.

Comment: This is gonna help me a lot in the future. The app is working perfectly but the scoreLabel still wont display

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47277/discussion-between-connor-and-crazycriss)

Answer (score 0):

The last solution suggested by @connor is correct. I suspect You might have run into issues of overlapping-layers (I was facing the same too & understand that it's often hard to figure out).

```
@implementation HelloWorldScene {
  //...
  CCLabelTTF * _label;
}

- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  //...
  _button     = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"button@2x.png"];
  _label      = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"A Button" fontName:@"Helvetica Neue" fontSize:14.0f];
  _button.position      = ccp( 100.0f, 100.0f);
  _label.position       = ccp( 100.0f, 100.0f);

  [self addChild:_button    ]; //make sure a button or any other layer goes before the label
  [self addChild:_label     ]; //label or any kind of text must be added last
}
```